# VB.NET Button Click event This page can't be displayed

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, internet-explorer, visual-studio-2012

My issue involves an aspx page that has a gridview with boundfields and templates with textboxes, drop down lists and a checkbox.  When the Create Collection button is clicked, it goes directly to the "This page can't be displayed".

I have a breakpoint set on the beginning of the click event.  This breakpoint is never triggered once the button is pressed.  The error screen comes up immediately.

One other note, the SelectCommand that populates the Gridview generally has anywhere from 1000 - 2400 items returned.  The OnRowDataBound function populates the dropdownlists in the template fields.

Everything works as it should with the exception of the last step; creating the collection in the SQL table and redirecting to the home page of the application.

[image]

VB.NET Code

```
Protected Sub btnCreate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCreate.Click
    Try
        For Each row As GridViewRow In grdCreate.Rows
            Dim chk As CheckBox = DirectCast(row.FindControl("chkSelect"), CheckBox)
            Dim qty As TextBox = DirectCast(row.FindControl("txtQty"), TextBox)
            Dim ref As DropDownList = DirectCast(row.FindControl("ddlRef"), DropDownList)
            Dim method As DropDownList = DirectCast(row.FindControl("ddlMethod"), DropDownList)
            Dim hours As TextBox = DirectCast(row.FindControl("txtHours"), TextBox)
            Dim equip As DropDownList = DirectCast(row.FindControl("ddlEquipment"), DropDownList)
            Dim saoi As TextBox = DirectCast(row.FindControl("txtSAOI"), TextBox)
            Dim notes As TextBox = DirectCast(row.FindControl("txtNotes"), TextBox)

            Dim count As Integer = 1
            If chk IsNot Nothing And chk.Checked Then
                strSql = "INSERT INTO [Collections] ([Collection], [Nomenclature], [PartNumber], [Reference], [Method], [Hours], [Equipment], [SAOI], [Notes]) " & _
                    "VALUES ('" & txtName.Text & "','" & row.Cells(1).Text & "','" & row.Cells(2).Text & "','" & _
                    ",'" & ref.SelectedItem.ToString & "','" & method.SelectedItem.ToString & "','" & hours.Text & "','" & equip.SelectedItem.ToString & "' " & _
                    ",'" & saoi.Text & "','" & notes.Text & "') "
                cmd = New SqlCommand(strSql, cnnNDI)
                cmd.CommandTimeout = 500
                cnnNDI.Open()
                If (qty.Text = "" Or qty.Text = "1") Then
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                Else
                    While count <= Convert.ToInt32(qty.Text)
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                        count = count + 1
                    End While
                End If
                cnnNDI.Close()
            End If
        Next
        Dim msg As String = "Collection Created"
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, GetType(Page), "class", "alert(""" & msg & """);", True)
        Response.Redirect("~/NDT/home.aspx")
    Catch ex As Exception
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, GetType(Page), "class", "alert(""" & ex.Message & """);", True)
    End Try
End Sub
```

ASPX Code

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdCreate" runat="server" AllowPaging="false" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="LightGray" DataSourceID="SQLCreate"
        align="center" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="grdCreate_RowDataBound">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelect" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Nomenclature" DataField="Nomenclature" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Part Number" DataField="PartNumber" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="QTY">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtQty" runat="server" Width="25px" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Reference">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlRef" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" Width="150px"
                        DataTextField="Reference" DataValueField="Reference">
                        <asp:ListItem>--SELECT--</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Method">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMethod" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true"
                        DataTextField="Method" DataValueField="Method">
                        <asp:ListItem>--SELECT--</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>ET</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>MT</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>PT</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>RT</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>UT</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>VT</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Hours">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtHours" runat="server" Width="25px" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Equipment">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEquipment" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" Width="150px"
                        DataTextField="Equipment" DataValueField="Equipment">
                        <asp:ListItem>--SELECT--</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Area of Interest">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSAOI" runat="server" Width="150px" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Result Notes">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtNotes" runat="server" Width="150px" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Concatenating notes.Text directly into your SQL leaves your app very vulnerable to SQL Injection. Q. What would strSql have in it if you typed: "'); DROP TABLE Collections --" in a notes field?     What is the value of the action attribute in the form tag of your aspx page?  Move your break-point into the page_load method and step through from there instead.

Comment: @HollyStyles, There is no action attribute in the Form tag.  I have placed breakpoints prior to the event but the results are still the same.  Once I click the button, I get the above page displayed.

Comment: did you try placing a breakpoint in the Page_Load section of your code as holly suggested? this will run first before your button click event and there is probably code here that is breaking your page on postback. or is there some kind of javascript attached to btnCreate? i do not see the markup for that button.

Comment: @taybriz, I just put the breakpoint on the page load and tested.  The same issue occurs.  Immediately after clicking the button, the error page displays.

Answer (score 0):

Use Command.CommandTimeout = 8000(or more) in Grid(Data)  binding

Comment: Try to explain why to do this to OP.

Comment: When you are binding more data at that time to load and execute your stored procedure its take some time. So to provide some time to execute your SP,  you can set 'CommandTimeout'.